# java application show progress on starting an application

Tags: java

We have a big java desktop application, which takes about minute to start, Currently we use splash screen on stat-up, Is it possible to show progress bar with splash screen...?
I mean when we start Some IDE like netbeans, IDEA Intellij, They show progress in form of progress-bar on splash screen. Progress bar might be showing progress in loading classes..
Thanks

Comment: Assuming you use Swing: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[swing]%20%2bsplash%20%2bprogress

Comment: You should be able to have the GUI available in a few seconds and background anything which takes longer than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the java [SplashScreen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) class. To set the progress bar you can draw a rectangle on the splash screen. As you hit different parts of your start up you can update this rectangle so that is acts like a progress bar. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/SplashDemoProject/src/misc/SplashDemo.java) demo code from Oracle show this. See the method titled renderSplashFrame()